# ActiveMQ Artemis - Is the "classic" configuration the correct one to use for a two-node replication with traffic from one virtual IP address?

Tags: replication, activemq-artemis

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74763071/apache-mq-artemis-how-to-configure-primary-secondary-on-two-vms-with-replicat), if I read it correctly, it was suggested that replication with ActiveMQ Artemis could be achieved with only two nodes as follows:

> However, it's still possible for the virtual IP address to direct traffic to one of the two VMs based on the broker's availability since the backup broker will not be able to receive connections until the primary broker fails at which point the backup broker will become active and begin accepting connections.

I'm assuming from the answer that this be accomplished simply using the classic HA policy to configure one as the master, the other as the slave and configuring them to be a part of the same cluster, as per [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/1.0.0/ha.html).

Is this a correct assumption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point from what you quoted from [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74763071/apache-mq-artemis-how-to-configure-primary-secondary-on-two-vms-with-replicat) was really just about the use of a virtual IP address in front of a primary/backup pair of brokers. I didn't mean to imply anything about the configuration of the primary/backup pair itself.

In short, even with a virtual IP address in front of the pair of brokers you *still* need a way to mitigate split brain and the minimum viable way to do that is with a ZooKeeper node. If you use the "classic" configuration approach then there will be no mitigation for split brain.